# Why in XAML XmlDataProvider do we have to say "x:Key" instead of "Key"?

Tags: wpf, xaml

What is the function of the namespace here?

I would think in this simple example I would be able to put "Key" and "XData" instead of "x:Key" and "x:XData" but when I do it says "Key" was not found in XmlDataProvider.

```
<Window x:Class="DataBindingWPF.XmlBinding"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DataBindingWPF" Height="300" Width="300"
    >
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Colors" Source="Colors.xml"  XPath="/colors"></XmlDataProvider>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MoreColors" XPath="/colors">
                <x:XData>
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Key" property is not an actual property of the XmlDataProvider. It's a Xaml attribute that lives in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" namespace you prefixed with "x".

StackPanel.Resources is a ResourceDictionary. In order to add something to a dictionary you need a Key/value pair. The Key attribute is the key for the resource, and the XmlDataProvider is the value. This is the mechanism WPF uses to uniquely identify resources.

You can change xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" to xmlns:ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" and then you would refer to it as "ns:Key" instead of "x:Key".

Answer (score 0):

Did you also remove the :x from

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

so it reads

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

Comment: yes, then I still get the same error, same as when you take the "x:" off of Class, the it says "Class is not a property of Window"